Using text field in Airflow DAG parameters
There are an option to pass string variable into Airflow DAG with Param class.
However, I want to pass the whole text, in my case: yaml as text.
I was trying to do it with array/object types of Param class, but "array" type just truncate each line of yaml file, and object type required JSON input.
I have no ability to convert yaml to json externally, so the only option for me is to pass yaml file to DAG param directly.
So how can I pass yaml file to Airflow text field?

One solution would be to use the Param class to receive a string. Internally, you will have to cast it to YAML before using it:

First, you need to define the DAG parameter as a string type.
 dag_params = {
 'yaml_config': Param(
     '',
     type='string',
     description='YAML configuration as a string'
 )
}


You will need to prepare your operator (in my case, PythonOperator) to perform the transformation from string to YAML.
 def parse_yaml(**kwargs):
     yaml_text = kwargs['dag_run'].conf['yaml_config']
     config = yaml.safe_load(yaml_text)
     print("Config loaded from YAML:", config)

 parse_config = PythonOperator(
     task_id='parse_yaml',
     python_callable=parse_yaml
 )


Finally, you will have the configuration available for use.


